# Grabbing json data from flask and printing it on an html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, flask

I've been stuck at this one particular part of web development for a while and can't seem to figure out how to do it correctly. Sometimes it prints out undefined, and sometimes if i change something it just prints out Object.

I have an app route that returns a jsonified array of dictionaries :

```
    @app.route('/test/resumes')
def test_page():
    j = get_resumes()
    return flask.jsonify(j=j)
```

I want to be able to use this data in my html code with the usage of js, jquery, and ajax.

Here's the script I'm currently using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("/test/resumes",function(data){
            var items =  [];
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                items.push('<li id=" ' + key + '">' + value+ '</li>');
            });
            $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'interest-list',
                html : items.join('')
            }).appendTo('body')


        });


    });
```

this is some of the output I get

```
Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
```

I counted the number of commas in the output and it's equal to the number of rows in the datatable

I'm still new to js, so this might look really poorly written.I'm usually develop on the backend side of things. I really just need to get over this hurdle of grabbing the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the JSON you are creating, this example would have to be adapted to yours.

In the view, you just pass the data along as before, I just added it so you can see how the JSON data looks for me.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/json',methods=['GET','POST'])
def json():
   j = [{"id":1, "username":"john"},{"id":2,"username":"doe"}]
   return jsonify(j=j)
```

In the HTML you first need to extract the `j` part of your JSON data. In the Javascript code the object that you sent will look like `{ j: [{..},{..}] }`. And then when you loop through the list of `j` the key will be the list index, and the value will be the JSON dict (for example `{"id":1, "username":"john"}`)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="application/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("/json",function(data){
            console.log(data.j);
            var items =  [];
            $.each(data.j, function(key, value){
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
            items.push('<li id=" ' + value.id + '">' + value.username+    '</li>');
        });
        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'interest-list',
            html : items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body')
        });
    });
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p> Text! </p>    
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the full example of my code which will display a list of two bullets, with the name john and doe. I've added console.log messages in the javascript so if you are not seeing anything on the webpage, check the console (In chrome I think you press CTRL+shift+i , and select console)

If this does not help you, you need to provide an example of the JSON data you are trying to display. And tell us what you are getting in the console.

Comment: I've tried this exact code and the webpage displays nothing

Comment: I've added the full example of my test app, this works for me. If it does not work for you, you need to supply more information on why it's not working. Check the console in the browser for any error messages, or the log messages that I've added. It's hard for me to debug a problem that occurs for you when the code works me. @BigBoy

Comment: And if it doesn't work, please paste the JSON your `get_resumes()` is returning.

Comment: plz mention the header files imported too. Will be helpful.